# HTML file parse section to csv

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, local

I am a newbie in Python. I am trying to get all the answers  from the executives (mentioned in the top) of a webpage (https://www.dropbox.com/s/uka24w7o5006ole/transcript-86-855.html?dl=0). This webpage is located on my harddrive (so no url).

So my end result would be:

```
Column 1  
All executives

Column 2  
all the answers
```

And answer should only be derived from the "question-and-answer-section".

What i tried was the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 

with open('transcript-86-855.html') as html_file:
    soup=BeautifulSoup(html_file, 'lxml')
article_qanda = soup.find('DIV', id='article_qanda'
```

Could someone please help me?

Comment: what you mean by column??? There is no such columns inside "article_qanda" node. Child nodes are just `p` tags.

Comment: i would like the output to be in columns. Maybe that was not clear in the question.

Comment: use `find_all()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to print two columns, one column is Name (in this case `Dror Ben Asher`), other column is his answer.

For example:

```
import textwrap
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('page.html', 'r') as f_in:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f_in.read(), 'html.parser')

print('{:<30} {:<70}'.format('Name', 'Answer'))
print('-' * 101)
for answer in soup.select('p:contains("Question-and-Answer Session") ~ strong:contains("Dror Ben Asher") + p'):
    txt = answer.get_text(strip=True)

    s = answer.find_next_sibling()
    while s:
        if s.name == 'strong' or s.find('strong'):
            break
        if s.name == 'p':
            txt += ' ' + s.get_text(strip=True)
        s = s.find_next_sibling()

    txt = ('\n' + ' '*31).join(textwrap.wrap(txt))

    print('{:<30} {:<70}'.format('Dror Ben Asher - CEO', txt))
    print()
```

Prints:

```
Name                           Answer                                                                
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Dror Ben Asher - CEO           Thank you, Scott. Its a very good question indeed in January we
                               announced a new amendment and that amendment includes anti-TNF
                               patients some of them not all of them, those who qualify. And we are
                               talking about anti-TNF failures to be clear and only Remicade and
                               Humira. The idea here was to increase very significantly the patients
                               pooled of those potentially eligible for the study thus expediting
                               recruitment. Did I answer your question?

Dror Ben Asher - CEO           Right, this is one of most important tasks; right now the most
                               important item here is the divestment of non-core assets. All other
                               non-core assets, the non-core assets are those that are not within our
                               therapeutic focus of GI and inflammation. And those are specifically
                               RHB-103 RIZAPORT for migraine and RHB-101 which is a cardio drug.
                               RHB-101 is a legacy drug, we have recently announced last month, we
                               announced that we are in discussions for both of these product for
                               out-licensing, which we hope to complete in the first half of 2015. So
                               this is the highest priority, obviously discussion on other product,
                               but Redhill is in the fortunate position that we are able to complete
                               our Phase III studies with our existing results, resources and as time
                               goes by obviously the value of the assets keeps going up. So we are in
                               no rush to out-license everything else and so there is obviously in
                               track.

...and so on.
```

Comment: awesome, only is it also possible to make it for all executives? And for multiple html files (these have the same setup of html)?

Comment: @nikos To scrape another executive, just replace `'Dror Ben Asher'` for another executive name. If you want to scrape multiple files, you could traverse current directory and open all `.html` files.

Comment: but is there no option to automatic recognize the "executives" (these are also in all the files different, but have the same HTML setup in all the files)?

Comment: how could i retrieve in a different column, the "symbolslug"? For this page the result should be RDHL in the third colum. And i would like to have all the executives not only `Dror Ben Asher`